# What is a "search space" in PPCoin and how is it used?

Tags: peercoin

[The PPCoin whitepaper](http://ppcoin.org/static/ppcoin-paper.pdf) describes "search space" without any context of what it is.  Can anyone describe what search space is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search space in cryptography refers to the sum of how many different solutions there can be. For example, a bit has a search space of 2 - 1 and 0, white a byte has a search space of 2^8 or 255.

In this context, the search space refers to how many different possible hashes there can be for the proof of stake (I believe) algorithm.